# SQL Server Select MAX Version Value

Tags: sql-server, max, sql-order-by

I have two columns in a table called id and version which looks like below :

```
ID | Version |
1  | A.15    |
1  | Z.6     |
1  | C.5     |
1  | BD.3    |
1  | BD.2    |
1  | AB.13   |
2  | C.45    |
2  | Z.56    |
2  | Z.8     |
```

My requirement is I have to select max(Version) for each id in the table. In this case I should get following result :

```
|ID | MAX(Version)|
| 1 | BD.3       |
| 2 | Z.56        |
```

But I am getting following result :

```
|ID | MAX(Version)|
| 1 | Z.6         |
| 2 | Z.8         |
```

when I use this query:

```
SELECT ID,MAX(Version)
FROM table
GROUP BY ID
```

Please suggest me good solution to get my desired result.
Thank you.

Comment: so the numeric portion represents the max version and alpha characters can be ignored?

Comment: When you say you want max ..then that means records should get sorted first..so accroding to you what should be sort order and why?According to string or varchar logic query is sorting correctly.So you need to share your sort order logic

Comment: First we have to consider max alphabets, in this case(ID=1) BD is greater than Z and then we have to consider the max number in that alphabet BD (34>25). So, result should be BD.34

Comment: how BD is greater than Z??

Comment: In my project , this is the case. Because it is version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE(ID INT, Version VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @MyTable
VALUES (1,'A.15'), (1,'Z.6'), (1,'C.5'), (1,'BD.3'), (1,'BD.2'),
       (1,'AB.13'), (2,'C.45'), (2,'Z.56'), (2,'Z.8')

--
SELECT
    ID,
    Version
FROM
(
    SELECT
        ID,
        Version,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
        (
            PARTITION BY    ID
            ORDER BY        LEN(LEFT(Version, CHARINDEX('.',Version)-1)) DESC, 
                            LEFT(Version, CHARINDEX('.',Version)-1) DESC, 
                            CAST(STUFF(Version, 1, CHARINDEX('.',Version),'') AS INT) DESC
        ) AS Pos
    FROM 
        @MyTable
) T
WHERE Pos = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can strip out the numeric part of the string by finding the value after the `.`, like so:

```
DECLARE @val VARCHAR(5) = 'BD.34'
SELECT  CONVERT(INT, RIGHT(@val, LEN(@val) - CHARINDEX('.', @val))) AS Result

Result
======
34
```

You can then factor this in to a subquery to join back on to you main table with `GROUP BY` and `MAX` like so:

**Runnable code:**

```
CREATE TABLE #Versions
    (
      [ID] INT ,
      [Version] VARCHAR(5)
    );

INSERT  INTO #Versions
        ( [ID], [Version] )
VALUES  ( 1, 'A.15' ),
        ( 1, 'Z.6' ),
        ( 1, 'C.5' ),
        ( 1, 'BD.34' ),
        ( 1, 'BD.25' ),
        ( 1, 'AB.13' ),
        ( 2, 'C.45' ),
        ( 2, 'Z.56' ),
        ( 2, 'Z.8' );

SELECT  v.ID ,
        v.Version
FROM    #Versions v
        INNER JOIN ( 
              SELECT ID , 
                     MAX(CONVERT(INT, 
                         RIGHT(Version, 
                           LEN(Version) - CHARINDEX('.', Version)))) AS VersionNo
                     FROM   #Versions
                     GROUP BY ID
                   ) t ON t.ID = v.ID
                          AND '.' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), t.VersionNo) = '.'
                          + RIGHT(v.Version,
                                  LEN(v.Version) - CHARINDEX('.', v.Version))

DROP TABLE #Versions
```

**Produces:**

```
ID  Version
1   BD.34
2   Z.56
```

The join used will join the `MAX` version number, held in `VersionNo` back to the main table, I've added `'.'` on to the join and have assumed that your versions will always be in the format of: characters followed by a period/full stop and the numeric portion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it is based on the number only but I required first it should consider the max alphabet (A,B,..,Z,AA,AB,...AZ,BA...,ZZ) and then in that max alphabet I have to select max version

Comment: @sanmathi that wasn't clear in the question, I can see your comment now, but you should know that important information should always be edited in to the question as opposed to adding a comment, as people wont always read them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the following:

```
SELECT ID,MAX(SUBSTRING(Version,charindex('.',Version),Len(Version)-charindex('.',Version)))
FROM table
GROUP BY ID
```

Basically the above code gets the substring after '.', thus the numeric part of Version and finds the max over that part

Comment: Thank you for answer . But I have to consider max alphabet also first and then number

Answer (score 0):

We dont need a group by here. It could be done with a relatively simple query. Logic used in the query is similar to the one used in other answer.

```
SELECT ID,version
FROM tmp a
where CAST(SUBSTRING(version,charindex('.',version)+1,Len(version)-charindex('.',version)) as integer)=
(select MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(version,charindex('.',version)+1,Len(version)-charindex('.',version)) as integer)) from tmp b where a.id=b.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my way for your case ( We don't care about the letters, only focus on number)

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE(ID INT, Version VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES(1,'A.15')
                    ,(1,'Z.6')
                    ,(1,'C.5')
                    ,(1,'BD.34')
                    ,(1,'BD.25')
                    ,(1,'AB.13')
                    ,(2,'C.45')
                    ,(2,'Z.56')
                    ,(2,'Z.8')


SELECT t1.ID, t1.Version 
FROM @MyTable AS t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Id, MAX(CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(Version,CHARINDEX('.',Version)+1,LEN(Version)))) AS Number
    FROM @MyTable
    GROUP By ID ) AS t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID AND CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(t1.Version,CHARINDEX('.',t1.Version)+1,LEN(t1.Version))) = t2.Number
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer .But alphabet in the version also plays important role